# Average data with the same key in an array of dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array in c# full of dictionaries.

For example:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, int>[] array = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>[numberOfArrays];
```

Then I fill them with keys and values like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<numberOfArrays; i++)
{
    array[i] = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>(); 

    foreach (var date in mySourceOfData)
    {     
       array[i].Add(date, value);
    }
}
```

Now I want to find all data inside my array "array" with a key that has a particular date, and Average the "values" for all the data with that key.

In other words I want to do something like this:

```
array.Value.Average(x=>x.key= myDate);
```

(I am not good at LINQ at all so the above might not make much sense...

I just want to average EVERY element inside the dictionary array "array" with a key "myDate" and produce another dictionary/variable that contains the averages.

All the arrays (array[i]) are of the same length.

Comment: Do you want the average for a _particular_ data or the average for _each_ date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all KeyValuePairs from all dictionaries. Then group them by key (i.e. by date) and convert groups to another dictionary, with date as key and average value from each group (i.e. from all KeyValuePairs of grouping date):

```
var averageByDate = array.SelectMany(d => d)
                         .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
                         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                                       g => g.Average(kvp => kvp.Value));
```

Then getting average for particular date will look like:

```
var average = averageByDate[someDate];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var avg = array.SelectMany(d => d)
    .Where(kvp => kvp.Key == myDate)
    .Average(kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
array.Average(x=>x[myDate]);
```

or

```
array.Where(d => d.ContainsKey(myDate)).Average(x=>x[myDate]);
```

if not all dictionaries will have that key.

Note that a `Dictionary<DateTime, int[]>` would make these queries a lot easier (and take less memory than an array of dictionaries).

Answer (score 0):

While you could just use Linq, something like

```
public decimal MeanForParticularDate( DateTime desired , Dictionary<DateTime,int>[] collection )
{
  decimal mean = collection
                 .SelectMany(
                   entry => entry
                            .Where(  x => x.Key == desired  )
                            .Select( x => (decimal) x.Value )
                   )
                 .Average()
                 ;
  return mean ;
}
```

I don't think that that is particularly more concise or understandable than the straightforward (and easier to debug) implementation:

```
public decimal MeanForParticularDate( DateTime desired , Dictionary<DateTime,int>[] collection )
{
  decimal n   = 0 ;
  decimal sum = 0 ;

  foreach( Dictionary<DateTime,int> dict in collection )
  {
    int value ;
    bool found = dict.TryGetValue( desired , out value ) ;

    if ( !found ) continue ;

    ++n ;
    sum += value ;

  }

  decimal mean = sum/n ;
  return mean ;
}
```

And I'm willing to bet that the latter performs significantly better than the former.